# Facebook share with static og tags and no app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to achieve a facebook share of a questionnaire results page.

I want the following items to be custom

1) The button, so I'm using an image
2) The Title, description and Image that appears in the Share box
3) The URL that is shared.

Here's the problem. The results are sent to a page called /results. This page changes depending on the visitors cookie (the results of their questionnaire is placed in this cookie so it displays the appropriate result).The OG tags for this page are also populated to get the right image, title and description to appear in the search box, but if Facebook were to scrape this page, it wouldn't be the same.

Here is the code I'm using

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '<?=FB_APP_ID?>',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.0'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<img src="images/icons/share-fb.png" alt="Share your Results on Facebook" class="share"/>

$('.share').click(function(){

FB.ui({
 method: 'share',
   href:'http://example.net/results',
}, function(response){});

 });
```

Is it at all possible to

1) Do this without having a Facebook App? Under FBs new rules I'm unable to get an app approved without the need for Facebook login which I neither need nor have.

2) Set what is shared and not have it change in a user's feed whenever facebooks scrapes the result page and doesn't see the relevant OG tags?

Comment: There is no way to override the scraping result that Facebook gets

Comment: Thanks. How do buzzfeed / upworthy do it when you take one of their quizzes and share the result?

Comment: I would guess they have a unique url per result